# Issue reproducing MATLAB's imfilter function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, convolution

I am trying to understand how MATLAB's `imfilter` function works.

```
im = imread("cameraman.tif");

% Kernel for sharpening the image
kernel = [
     0 -1  0;
    -1  5 -1;
     0 -1  0];

im2 = zeros(size(im));

for y = 1 : size(im,1) - 3
    for x = 1 : size(im,2) - 3

        sum = 0;
        for ky = 1:3
            for kx = 1:3
                xx = x + kx - 1;
                yy = y + ky - 1;
                sum = sum + im(yy,xx)*kernel(ky,kx);
            end
        end
        
        im2(y,x) = sum;
    end
end

% Map im2 to 0 - 255
im2 = im2 - min(im2(:));
im2 = im2 / max(im2(:)) * 255;
im2 = uint8(im2);

subplot(131), imshow(im), title('Original Image')
subplot(132), imshow(imfilter(im,kernel)), title('Matlab imfilter')
subplot(133), imshow(im2), title('My filter')
```

Differences at the boundaries are not my concern but my result (the subplot at the right) is clearly different than what MATLAB produces (the middle subplot) although the same kernel was used.

[image]

May I know what could be the deviation? As far as I know, kernel patch will be applied to the image element-wise and be summed over the result. Could someone let me know what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: Your image is likely uint8, in which case you're exceeding the max value that it can hold (255). Convert it to double, do your calculations, then truncate, round, and convert it back to uint8.

Comment: Thanks beaker. I mapped `im2` to 0-255 by using `im2 = im2 - min(im2(:));`, `im2 = im2 / max(im2(:)) * 255;`, and `im2 = uint8(im2);` but it does not make a difference on the result. I have updated my question with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bug is in this line:

```matlab
sum = sum + im(yy,xx)*kernel(ky,kx);
```

This is not obvious, but MATLAB makes a strange choice when doing arithmetic with different data types. In MATLAB, by default all numeric arrays (all values) are doubles. `sum` is double* when you initialize it (`sum = 0`), as are `kernel` and `im2`. But `im` is an 8-bit unsigned integer array. So `im(yy,xx)*kernel(ky,kx)` does a multiplication of a uint8 with a double. This is the strange case of combining different data types in an operation.

When doing arithmetic with an integer array, the other operand must be of the same type, unless it is a double scalar (a 1x1 double array). In this case, the scalar value is converted to the integer type, then the operation is applied. Also, integer arithmetic is saturated, meaning that any result outside of the integer range is clamped to the range (there is no overflow as in other languages).

So `im(yy,xx)*kernel(ky,kx)` results in a uint8. Next, `sum + <uint8 result>` is also a uint8 value, which is assigned to `sum`. Now `sum` is uint8!

To fix this, do

```matlab
sum = sum + double(im(yy,xx)) * kernel(ky,kx);
```

---

* Also note that everything is an array. `0` is a 1x1 array.

---

**Unsolicited advice:**

1. You should not scale the `im2` image, you should directly cast it to `uint8`. MATLAB will clamp the values to the [0,255] range for you. Scaling causes loss of contrast.
2. Don't use `sum` as a variable name. `sum` is a built-in function, which you shadow (make unavailable) with this variable. After running your code, you can no longer do `sum(im(:))`, for example.
3. The inner two loops are very easily vectorized:

   ```matlab
   tmp = double(im(x + (0:2), y + (0:2))) .* kernel;
   im2(y,x) = sum(tmp(:));
   ```

   or, in very recent versions of MATLAB,

   ```matlab
   im2(y,x) = sum(double(im(x + (0:2), y + (0:2))) .* kernel, 'all');
   ```

   (And note the need for the `sum` function here!)

Comment: Nicely explained. Thank you. So, if the pixel value for the image after convolution has, for example, a value outside of `0-255`, it'll be clamped to `0` or `255` using `uint8` regardless of how close or far they are from 0 and 255? So a value of `-322` become `0` and a value of `+1000` becomes `255`?

Comment: @user578 Yes, that is right. This is very easy to test in MATLAB: Try `uint8(-43423)` at the command prompt.